# Entity Framework Core 2 one to one relationship "on one table"

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api, ef-core-2.0

I have an entity that have a one to one relationship with itself:

```
public class Link
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long OtherLinkId { get; set; }
    public Link OtherLink { get; set; }
}
```

How can I define this relationship with fluent API?

My solution:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Link>()
            .HasOne(x => x.OtherLink)
            .WithOne(x => x.OtherLink)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

but on migration, it tries to create a second `OtherLink`.

Comment: Did you try without using the fluent api? EF should deduce it alone.

Comment: This cannot work anyway. You cannot insert an item without a `OtherLinkId` (given that it is required) and you cannot obtain an `OtherLinkId` without first inserting it. You need to make `OtherLinkId` optional: `public long? OtherLinkId`

Comment: Have you found another solution or answers below don't solve your issue?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by using a nullable `ForeignKey` attribute in your model class.

```
public class Link
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long? OtherLinkId { get; set; } = null;

    [ForeignKey("OtherLinkId")]
    public Link OtherLink { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify it. EF [conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#fully-defined-relationships) can't find it without your help.

If you don't want to follow the convetions and need to specify it using data annotation attribute `ForeignKey` like below:

```
[ForeignKey("OtherLinkId")]
public Link OtherLink { get; set; }
```

Or using fluent configuration:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Link>()
            .HasOne(x => x.OtherLink)
            .WithOne(x => x.OtherLink)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.OtherLinkId);
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

**Important side note:**
Your foreign key property should be nullable without that you'll not be able to insert item to your table `OtherLink`.

Your final code should look like this:

```
public class Link
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long? OtherLinkId { get; set; } // <- Without this you'll be unable to insert a single link.

    [ForeignKey("OtherLinkId")] // <- remove this if you use Fluent Configuration.
    public Link OtherLink { get; set; }
}
```